# Algorithm to judge whether two expressions are equivalent

Tags: algorithm, math, arithmetic-expressions

Given two arithmetic expressions e1 and e2 that have same four operands, judge if they are equivalent.
Two expression are equivalent if they can be arranged to be the same expression
according to mathematical properties.
Return true if they are equivalent, otherwise false.

I just cannot figure out an algorithm to solve this problem.
I need this algorithm to solve the problem to list all solutions without
replication of [24 Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_(puzzle)).

### Examples

Example 1:

- Input: e1 is "6 * (2 + 5 - 3)", e2 is "(5 - 3 + 2) * 6".
- Output: true

Example 2:

- Input: e1 is "5 - (2 - 7 * 3)", e2 is "3 * 7 + 5 - 3".
- Output: true

Example 3:

- Input: e1 is "(7 + 5) / (2 / 4)", e2 is "(7 + 5) * 4 / 2".
- Output: true

Example 4:

- Input: e1 is "(7 + 5) * 4 / 2", e2 is "(7 + 5) * (4 - 2)".
- Output: false.

### Constraints

- e1 and e2 have exactly the same four integer number as operands that is between 1 to 10.
- Only four basic binary arithmetic operation can be used:
  `addition(+), subtraction(-), multiplication(*), division(/)`.
- Minus(-) can only be used as a subtraction operator and not as a unary operator to
  compute the numeric negation of its operand.
- Parentheses can be used.

Comment: Construct the parsing tree, compact it to canonical form, then compare the tree shape.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans what is the canonical form? Expanded out with variables in alphabetical order?

Comment: There is no "the" when it comes to canonical forms, canonical form just means that given your rewrite rules, all equivalent expressions are guaranteed to end up looking the same. So yes, fully expanded with the nodes ordered by variable name would certainly be one such form.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think you're glossing your way past some major challenges when it comes to rational expressions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75932183/585411 for a description of how to handle the challenges around rational expressions.

Comment: @btilly absolutely, which is why it's a comment: it gives the OP a chance to look up terms that are applicable to this problem that they didn't know before, allowing them to (re)search anew and find tutorials/webpages/SO questions about them, getting them unstuck. Because knowing what to look for gets you back to step 2: [search, and research](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "I need this algorithm to solve the problem to list all solutions without replication of 24 Game" -- no, you don't.  What you're asking for is a lot harder than what you're trying to use it for.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I would be more inclined to agree if I thought you sent them in a direction that was likely to be helpful. I don't, and recognizing that `a/a - b/(b+c)` is the same as `c/(b+c)` shows how unhelpful the rabbit hole you sent them down is.

Comment: Except division by zero is not allowed in arithmetics, so why would we ever expect to see an expression that has a division by zero unless and until the exercise actually tells us we need to account for that?

Comment: Modified the question to make it more specific and limited. I have to admitted the question is far more challenge that I thought.

Comment: Looks like a really interesting question. I don't know at what level you're required to work. My advice is to work with a computer algebra system to handle the rearrangement to a canonical form, including taking GCD into account. You still need to enumerate the possible expressions and test each pair for equality in order to establish equivalence classes of same-value expressions, and then filter the equivalence classes to see which ones solve a specific problem. If you get all that stuff working, you can circle back and implement simplification and/or GCD. Take a look at Sympy or Maxima.

Answer (score 1):

Finding an algorithm to solve this is challenging, since a special case of the problem as you've presented it is determining whether to polynomials are equivalent.

[Polynomial identity testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_testing) has unknown computational complexity, but it's known that brute force solutions can take exponential time. Therefore, the standard approach to this is to use randomized inputs and test for equality using the [Schwartz-Zippel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma).

I expect that writing an implementation of this will be easier than other approaches and have better performance.

Note that you need to be careful of both [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and [floating-point issues](https://www.itu.dk/%7Esestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) in implementing this. For your case, it's probably sufficient to use unsigned 64-bit integers or long doubles.

You may worry about the probabilistic nature of the algorithm. But consider that we can transfer the question of whether `p=q` into the question of whether `p-q=0`. If `p-q` is zero across its entire range, then `p=q`. Otherwise, `p-q` is a `d`-degree polynomial with at most `d` points where it equals zero. If we choose test values from a set `S` of size `|S|` then the probability of finding one of these points is `d/|S|`, which becomes small as `|S|` grows. If we make multiple evaluations we can drive the probability even lower.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to evaluate anything here, rather than looking at the arithmetic parsing tree? You don't actually care about what values the symbols can take on, you just want to rewrite the expressions to a canonical form that you can then directly compare.

Comment: No floating point issues as all numbers (coefficients) involved are integer, and variables remain as symbols

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: There's not an efficient algorithm that can do such a rearrangement for the general case, though perhaps there is one for this limited set of operators.

Comment: @Richard There definitely is one for this limited set of operators.

Comment: @Richard absolutely, but this question isn't about all of calculus, just arithmetics, and doesn't even allow the unitary minus sign. A time-honred computer science homework exercise for the "write a math parser" class =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I think btilly's answer addresses what you're saying. As they've pointed out, even in this simple situation you can get complex situations and exponential runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe an approach, and indicate another more complex, but more efficient, approach.

If you didn't include division, then there would be a simple way to do this.  Namely you multiply everything out, get a polynomial, write each term in lexicographic order (ie `a` before `b`, etc), then sort the terms in lexicographic order (by power of `a`, by power of `b`, etc), then combine like terms.  This would turn each expression into a normalized form.  Expressions match if and only if the polynomials match.

As @Richard notes, this algorithm has exponential complexity.  But with only 4 operands, its complexity will be fine.  You will have to think carefully while coding it, but you should be able to succeed.

BUT..we have division.

There are two ways you can go.

The simplest is to multiply out top and bottom to a multivariate polynomial of the form `X/Y`.  If you want to know whether `X1/Y1 = X2/Y2` you cross multiply and see whether `X1*Y2 = X2*Y1`.  This requires pairwise comparisons between every pair of expressions.  For a one time operation, this may be acceptable.

If it is not, then it is time to go down a rabbit hole.  We need to put `X/Y` itself into normalized form.  That requires computing a GCD, which [Polynomial GCDs by Syzygies](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7829593) provides an algorithm for.  To complete normalized form we not only want to be in the form `X/Y` with `GCD(X, Y) = 1`, but we also want to make sure that `Y` is in normalized form with a *positive* leading coefficient.  (If the coefficient winds up negative, multiply top and bottom by `-1`.)

And now all of the expressions can be normalized, you can then compare (eg sort them), and see which are the same.

Good luck!

Comment: The method is globally ok. however, I would use as normalized form a list of terms. Each term defined by the number of occurences (that may be negative if term is preceeded by "-") and a list of items sorted by variable name. Each item being defined by the value identifying the variable and the "power" (1 indicates how many time the item is found, negative numbers denote that the variable is in the denominator. For comparison, a sort method is required, if the number of terms of the 2 expressions are different.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The problem as stated allows `a/a - b/(b+c)`. Without some sort of GCD logic, how will you recognize that this is the same as `c/(b+c)`? (Note, values must be integers greater than 0 so `a/a` is guaranteed not to blow up.)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No additional rules. Read the problem again. `a/a - b/(b+c)` uses 6 operands, only allowed operations, and is the same for all positive integer inputs as `c/(b+c)`. You can only forbid it by insisting on rules not stated in the problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I would need to see working code to believe that it is always trivial. Because I don't think it is, and can easily imagine code in which it is not.

Comment: removed my comments that were detracting from the answer.